# Error in createDataFrame in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file that has (x, y, z) coordinates of 10 frames of a object. When I create the Data Frame, I get error. The code is given below.

```
 val schema_each_atom = Row(Seq(
 StructField("x", DoubleType, false),
 StructField("y", DoubleType, false),
 StructField("z", DoubleType, false)))

 var file_text = sc.textFile(file_name)
 var header = file_text.first() 
 file_text = file_text.filter(row => row != header)

 var temp_data = file_text.map(s => regex.findAllMatchIn(s).
     map(_.matched.toDouble).toList).collect.toList.flatten.toList
 var frames_from_file = temp_data.grouped(10).toList

 frames_from_file.foreach { x => 
   var each_atom_coord = x.grouped(number_of_atoms).toList.map(x => x.toSeq)

   var rdd_each_atom_coord = sc.makeRDD(each_atom_coord)
   var frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_each_atom_coord, schema_each_atom)
 }
```

The last line gives error.

Comment: What error? Please post stacktrace

Comment: Value rdd is not a member of String  (rdd_each_atom_coord) and Value schema is not a member of String (schema_each_atom)

Comment: I suggest that you take a step back and review the core concepts of Spark and Scala. I'm afraid that that code does not make sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323 The arguments passed seem right to me but it still doesn't accept the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/764040/maasg  I have read the documentations but the examples are very crude and do not tend to the problem I am dealing with.